# Mapped network drives aren't showing in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, samba, group-policy, network-drive

Recently I've started to migrate a domain from Windows Server 2003 (mapping drives by script) to a Samba 4 DC (mapping drives by GPO).
Most of the computers work fine, but on some of them I've noticed that some drives are not showing in Windows Explorer and, after some research I've noticed this:

- The drives that aren't showing are not always the same drives, it happens randomly and sometimes all the drives are OK
- The drives are always mounted. If I use the command `net use` on cmd it shows all the drives.
- To mount the drive I've to unmount the old first using cmd, and then mount the drive again. After this the drive shows up in explorer.
- There is not local drive with the same letter so is not a conflict
- The GPO info shows that all the GPO are applied without problem

I've also checked that there's no registry entry to hide the drive and also I've changed the option to show the drive on drive policy, but nothing worked.

I'm using Windows 10 and I think that I also had this problem in a Windows 7 computer.

Did anyone have similar problems?

Comment: I experience this all the time on Windows 10, especially if I am using "use other credentials" across multiple PCs, different clients.  I am yet to find a solution, so I shall favorite this question ;)

Comment: What "Action" have you got set? Create, Update? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770902(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: The action I use is update. With this action the client should create the drive if not exists... and that's OK, the client create that drives and are showed on command line, but the Windows Explorer fails and don't show some of that drives. 
It only happens on some clients and I think that all are using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by restarting the Explorer process.

See [Can't see windows 10 mapped drive in windows explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/989223/cant-see-windows-10-mapped-drive-in-windows-explorer/1726846#1726846)

But it would be nice if there was a less drastic way, are more script-friend way.